# Google map : can any one help me to set below location in my code?

Tags: html, google-maps

```
<div class="map">
    <iframe width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Lighthouse+Point,+FL,+United+States&amp;aq=4&amp;oq=light&amp;sll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;sspn=0.04941,0.104628&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Lighthouse+Point,+Broward,+Florida,+United+States&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Lighthouse+Point,+FL,+United+States&amp;aq=4&amp;oq=light&amp;sll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;sspn=0.04941,0.104628&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Lighthouse+Point,+Broward,+Florida,+United+States&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.275636,-80.087265" style="color:#777;text-align:left;font-size:0.85em">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>
```

i want to set this location https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Railway+Basketball+Court/@23.338003,75.046929,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xdc7e2bda17b6799e

in above code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851089/using-google-maps-api-how-can-we-set-the-current-location-as-the-default-set-lo..

Just check this link.. It might be helpful for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will set both your maps to point to the basketball court

```
<div class="map">
<iframe width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7326.773276182955!2d75.046929!3d23.338003!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdc7e2bda17b6799e!2sRailway+Basketball+Court!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1398926727930" ></iframe>
<br>
<small>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Railway+Basketball+Court/@23.338003,75.046929,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xdc7e2bda17b6799e" style="color:#777;text-align:left;font-size:0.85em">View Larger Map</a>
</small>
</div>
```

you can also go on the google map when its opened to the gear in the bottom right open the dropup menu go to share and embed map and click embed map and it will generate the iframe for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7326.773276182956!2d75.046929!3d23.338003!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xdc7e2bda17b6799e!2sRailway+Basketball+Court!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1398929598162" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
</iframe>
```

for further info click on the settings icon on the maps on the down left corner and click on share or embed map